# Python web scraping with Selenium and Pandas - Length of values ( ) does not match length of index?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

When I ran the following code I saw it gone through all the 17 or 18 pages that I wish to scrape, and suddenly error message popped up, is that about pandas (ValueError: Length of values (429) does not match length of index (18))?

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\centranet_v1.chrome 20230219.py", line 98, in <module>
    df['Address'] = Address
    ~~^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3980, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4174, in _set_item
    value = self._sanitize_column(value)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4915, in _sanitize_column
    com.require_length_match(value, self.index)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 571, in require_length_match
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Length of values (429) does not match length of index (18)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

### My code is as follows,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd


# In[11]:


#open chrome web browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://hk.centanet.com/findproperty/en/list/transaction")


# class element_id_class(object):
#     def __init__(self, locator, css_class):
#         self.locator = locator
#         self.css_class = css_class
#     def __call__(self, driver):
#         element = driver.find_element(*self.locator)
#         if self.css_class in element.get_attribute("class"):
#             return element
#         else:
#             return False

# In[12]:


#find elements in web page
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
inputElem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "input")))
inputElem.clear()
inputElem.send_keys('Discovery Park')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn-search"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn-fiter']/span[contains(text(),     'Sold / Leased')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='el-radio__label']/span[contains(text(), 'Sold')]"))).click()
click_next = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn-next")))


# In[13]:


Date=Address=Price=Changes=Saleable_Area=[]
def it(x):
    lst=[]
    for i in x:
        lst.append(i.text)
    return lst


# In[14]:


while True:
    content = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='bx--structured-list-td']")
    info_date = content.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"info-date")
    Date = Date + it(info_date)
    info_address = content.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cv-structured-list-data bx--structured-list-td']/div[contains(text(), 'Discovery Park')]")
    Address = Address + it(info_address)
    tranprice = content.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"tranPrice")
    Price = Price + it(tranprice)
    info_changes = content.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"riseBox")
    Changes = Changes + it(info_changes)
    feet = content.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cv-structured-list-data bx--structured-list-td']/div[contains(text(), 'ft²')]")
    Saleable_Area = Saleable_Area + it(feet)
    if click_next.is_enabled():
        click_next.click()
    else:
        break #break the while loop if click next is disable
    sleep(2)
driver.quit()




# In[15]:


df = pd.DataFrame()


# In[16]:


df['Date'] = Date
df['Address'] = Address
df['Price'] = Price
df['Changes%'] = Changes
df['Saleable_Area'] = Saleable_Area


# In[17]:


df


# In[18]:


df.to_csv("result2.csv", index=False)
```

18 pages of property transaction records export as csv

Answer (score 1):

## Solution:

The CSS selector for your `content` is incorrect. You have

```
content = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='bx--structured-list-td']")
```

but you need to have

```
content = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='bx--structured-list-tbody']")
```

## Explanation

The reason you're getting this error is that your lists are not the same length. The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\centranet_v1.chrome 20230219.py", line 98, in <module>
    df['Address'] = Address
...
ValueError: Length of values (429) does not match length of index (18)
```

refers to your `Address` list having length of 429, whereas your index is length 18 (because `Date` is length 18 and you used that to initiate your DataFrame.

When I run the following:

```py
#In[6]:
len(Date),len(Address),len(Price),len(Changes),len(Saleable_Area)

#Out[6]:
18,429,0,0,429
```

This is happening because you set

```py
content = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='bx--structured-list-td']")
```

and it was only retrieving 1 date per page, and was not fetching the price or changes.

Hope this helps.